# openpyxl readonly use_iterators

Tags: python, xlsx, openpyxl

I have some huge Excel files, but I'm stymied with even a "modest" one (50 Mbytes). I do need to skip over the first two rows, but I don't think that's the slowdown. Can you think of something else?

```
wb = load_workbook(MyFile,read_only=True)
ws = wb.active

NDepth = ws.max_row-2
NTime = ws.max_column -1

Local_Depth = np.zeros((NDepth,))
Local_Temp = np.zeros((NDepth,NTime))

iterlist = islice(ws.iter_rows(),2,None)

start = time.time()

i=0
for row in iterlist:
    Local_Depth[i] = row[0].value 
    j=0
    for col in row[1:]:
        Local_Temp[i,j] = col.value
        j += 1
    i += 1

print "Done", time.time()-start
```

It's taking me well over 7 minutes to load the file on a M4700 Dell Precision. About 8000 rows and 800 columns. Surely there must be something wrong? Could there be some other tweaks somewhere that I should be making in my Python 2.7 set-up?

Thank, John

Comment: It depends on what are you going to do with the data that you are reading from this excel file... I, personally, would use Pandas module for that - it's very easy and uses inside very nice and fast algorithms

Comment: 7*60 / (8000*800) ~= 0,066 miliseconds/cell which doesn't seem too bad.

Comment: Have you tried running the code without iterators, i.e. `use_iterators=False`?

Comment: If you think there is a bottleneck somewhere then you should always profile your code. A file with only 8000 * 800 cells should be a lot smaller than 50 MB.

Comment: If I convert XLSX (49.5 MB) to CSV I get 46.517 MB. If I extract unzip the Sheet.XML it is 260MB

Comment: If I keep read_only and set use_iterators to False then no difference (~477 seconds) but if I don't use read-only then phew, maybe an hour. Dunno, I gave up waiting.

Comment: If you don't use read-only mode then you will be loading 64 million cells. Even using slots that's using a lot of memory – probably about 6 or 7 GB but should be loadable in a about 10 minutes. If it's taking longer then your system is swapping a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I am down to 22 seconds

```
import numpy as np
import time
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import zipfile


def rowList(fullfilename):
with  zipfile.ZipFile(fullfilename, mode='r') as z: 
    with z.open('xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml', 'r') as f:
        irow =-1
        while irow <0:
            hstring = f.read(50000)
            if hstring == "":
                break;
            irow = hstring.find("sheetData")
            if irow < 0:
                return
        string = hstring[irow+10:] 
        while True:
            irow = string.find("</row>")
            while irow<0:
                hstring = f.read(50000)
                if hstring == "":
                    break;
                string += hstring
                irow = string.find("</row>")
            if irow < 0:
                return
            irow +=6 
            ist = string.find("<c")
            yield string[ist:irow-6]
            string = string[irow:]


def splitRow(func,row):

j = 0
c1 = row.find("<v")
c2 = 0
while c1 > 0: 
    c1 += c2 + 3
    c2 = c1 + row[c1:].find("</v")
    yield func(row[c1:c2])
    j += 1
    c2 += 3
    c1 = row[c2:].find("<v")


start = time.time()

wb = load_workbook(MyFile,read_only=True, use_iterators=True) 
ws = wb.active
NDepth = ws.max_row-2
NTime = ws.max_column -1
wb._archive.close()

Local_Store = np.empty((NDepth,NTime+1))
Local_Time = np.empty((NTime,))

print NDepth, NTime
print "Data Accessed via Iterators", time.time()-start

start = time.time()

print "About to call RowList"

i = -2
j = 1
for row in rowList(MyFile): 
if i == -2:
    True 
else:
    if i == -1:
        Local_Time[:] = list(splitRow(float,row))
    else:
        Local_Store[i,:] = list(splitRow(float,row))

i += 1  

print i, "Rows Parsed", time.time()-start
```

Comment: To parse the row, I did try  root = ET.fromstring(row); mylist = root.itertext(); floaty = map(float,mylist) but it once again went back slower than a dog. The call to OpenPyXL to get dimensions was barely hundredth of a second.

Answer (score 0):

I would try pandas for this task. It's very simple and gives you lots of power.

Here is a small example:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# let's generate some sample data (8000 rows, 800 columns)
data = np.random.randint(0, 100, (8000, 800))

# let's generate column names from 'col001' to 'col800'
cols = ['col{0:02d}'.format(i) for i in range(1,801)]

# generating Pandas data frame from numpy array
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

# write generated DF (Data Frame) to Excel file
df.to_excel(r'd:/temp/sample.xlsx', index=False)
# we are done with sample data

#####################################################################
#
# interesting part starts here ...
#
#####################################################################

start = time.time()

# read up the Excel file (skipping first two rows)
df = pd.read_excel(r'd:/temp/sample.xlsx', skiprows=2)

print "Done", time.time()-start

# print the shape of out DF
print(df.shape)
```

Output (from iPython, on my home notebook it took approx. 2 minutes):

```
In [24]: %paste
start = time.time()

# read up the Excel file
df = pd.read_excel(r'd:/temp/sample.xlsx', skiprows=2)

print "Done", time.time()-start
## -- End pasted text --
Done 124.375999928

In [25]:

In [25]: df.shape
Out[25]: (7998, 800)

In [26]: # print the shape of out DF

In [27]: print(df.shape)
(7998, 800)
```

Now you have all your data in memory as a DF and can process it very comfortable using all Panda's power

PS you would need to install the following Python modules:

- numpy
- pandas
- xlrd
- openpyxl or XlsxWriter  (or both)

Comment: Performance when reading large Excel files is very similar for openpyxl and xlrd (which is what Pandas uses internally for reading). In both cases, as the data is stored row by rows, Pandas needs to convert the rows into columns before it can do anything. So, for a simple operation this won't run faster. Of course, Pandas will be faster for aggregate operations.

Answer (score -1):

If I take as a given that the Excel file is a rectangular sheet then I get a huge speed up by just going to ZIP directly. Attached is part of the code for generator that returns a series of rows that I can then parse to search for the actual values between `<v>` and `</v>` in each row. I haven't attempted to pretty this up - it looks very non-Pythony.

```
def rowList():
with  zipfile.ZipFile('MyFile.xlsx', mode='r') as z: 
    with z.open('xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml', 'r') as f:
        irow =-1
        while irow <0:
            hstring = f.read(50000)
            if hstring == "":
                break;
            irow = hstring.find("sheetData")
        if irow < 0:
            return
        ist = hstring.find("<dimension")
        string = hstring[ist+16: ist+50]
        itl = string.find("/>")
        yield  string[:itl-1]
        string = hstring[irow+10:] 
        while True:
            irow = string.find("</row>")
            while irow<0:
                hstring = f.read(50000)
                if hstring == "":
                    break;
                string += hstring
                irow = string.find("</row>")
            if irow < 0:
                return
            irow +=6
            ist = string.find("<c")
            yield string[ist:irow-6] 
            string = string[irow:]
```

Drops computation time from minutes to seconds.

Which makes me wonder if there is something similar being considered for openpyxl - a parameter to tell it that is opening a very flat file.

Comment: While xlsx files are always zip archives, this approach is extremely inflexible and error prone. For example, the dimension tag is very likely to be missing. This is why you must use some kind of XML library for reading the source. As it turns out iterparse is very fast. I suspect the difference in speed you are observing is caused by something completely different.

Comment: Throwing in the parsing for columns <v> ... </v> gets me 105 seconds for the full data load. Not as fast as the panda example below it seems. I agree that this hack above should not be the way to go, but it does maybe help clarify the bottleneck. Openpyxl was perfectly fast in finding the dimensions. I had left the <dimension search in the pseudo-code above only because I was curious where it was.

Comment: If you run any profiling you'll see that time is spent on converting the string value of the cell into the appropriate Python value (number, boolean, datetime, string or formula). There is some overhead associated in instantiating Cell objects which a custom parser could avoid. But using pypy should give you the best boost.